# How thick is the neural tube at Stage 10 in a chick embryo?

Tags: development, chickens

As the question states - I am really struggling to find ANY website/paper/article which states this. I want to know if the neural tube is still one cell thick and stage 10 of development. Any evidence that can be supplied to show this would be useful.

Thanks